# After upgrading to 20.04 I lost my WiFi

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04

After I upgraded a PC with 18.04 Ubuntu to 20.04 my wifi won't work. After some troubleshooting, I have found that if I have an ethernet cable plugged into the network the wifi says it can't find an adapter, but if you unplug the network cable the wifi comes on and you can pick any SSID that is listed and seems to work as it should. If you plug in the network cable again the wifi shuts off again. Can someone explain why after the upgrade the wifi would work like this?

Comment: This is an expected behavior. And you haven't "lost your wifi". The question title is wrong.

Comment: @Pilot6 Are you sure? What if I want two network connections at the same time? Why would I want one to go down when I connect the other?

Comment: You can't have two network connections at the same time without setting some routing manually.

Comment: I disagree. I currently have two connections to my LAN. No manual routing specified anywhere. The TCP/IP stack *probably* selects the faster interface to use, but I don't care about that. Both interfaces are up, and I can ping through both of them.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure there isn't something wrong and it was intended to be this way. I like the idea but my users are going to ask about why they don't have wifi at the same time.